# read file from a file based on specific order

Tags: python

I have a file that contains 15 files and they are named respectively from 1 to 15. I used the following code for reading all the files in the specific directory:

```
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
```

but it read the files named from 1 to 15 and then 2 to 9. is it a way to read files respectively as 1,2,3,...,15?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post only one question at a time.

Comment: @mcsoini In this case, the two questions are interrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your two questions are actually interrelated.

To sort the output of `listdir` with the "natural" numeric sort order, you'll need that function to extract the number. You can then use that function as the `key` function argument to `sorted()` (or `list.sort()`).

See below; I have a mock `listdir()` since I don't have those files, but you would naturally use your own `os.listdir()` in your own code.

```
import os


def listdir():
    return sorted(fr"C:/output5000k/{x}.mp4" for x in range(1, 16))


def get_file_number(path: str) -> int:
    basename = os.path.basename(path)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
    return int(filename)


print(sorted(listdir(), key=get_file_number))
```

This prints out

```
['C:/output5000k/1.mp4', 'C:/output5000k/2.mp4', 'C:/output5000k/3.mp4', 'C:/output5000k/4.mp4', ...]
```

as expected.

Comment: I use this tmp=sorted(fr"C:\Users\jamalm8\ffmpeg\UGCvideos\LyricVideo\LyricVideo_8000k/{x}.mp4" for x in range(1, 16)) but the output is the same as before. what is the problem? is sorted a function of python?

Comment: It is. But as said, you need that key function I illustrated to extract the number part as a number.